# Updating MutableLiveData on MainThread RXAndroid

Tags: java, android, rx-android, rx-java2, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to learn about `Android Architecture Components` and `RXJava/RXAndroid` and converting a poorly written old project.

I want my DB to be the single source of truth so I have a `MovieRepository` class which makes the call to the API, inserts it into a DB, and then fetches the movies from the DB and sends it to the `ViewModel`.

My MovieRepository class -

```
public Completable getMovies(String sortPref) {
        Timber.d("test repo getmovies");
        if (!sortPref.equals("favorite")) {

            Single<MoviesResponse> movieFlowable = movieService.getMovies(sortPref, BuildConfig.OPEN_TMDB_API_KEY);

            return movieFlowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMapCompletable(moviesResponse -> {
                            for (MovieInfo movie : moviesResponse.getMovies()) {
                            movie.setPosterUrl("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + movie.getPosterPath());
                            movie.setSortSetting(sortPref);
                            movie.setVoterRating(movie.getRating() + "/10");
                        }

                        return insertMovies(moviesResponse.getMovies()).andThen(getMoviesFromDB(sortPref));
                    });
        } else {
            return getMoviesFromDB(sortPref);
        }
    }

    public LiveData<List<MovieInfo>> getMoviesLiveData() {
        return movies;
    }

    private Completable getMoviesFromDB(String sortPref) {
        Timber.d("test get movies from db");
        return Completable.fromAction(() -> movies = movieDatabase.getMovieDao().getMoviesBySortSetting(sortPref))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    private Completable insertMovies(List<MovieInfo> movies) {
        Timber.d("test insert movies in db");
        return Completable.fromAction(() -> movieDatabase.getMovieDao().insertAll(movies)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
```

My `MovieFragmentViewModel` class has the method `loadMovies()` which subscribes to the cold Completable.

```
public LiveData<List<MovieInfo>> getMovieInfo() {
    if (movieInfo == null) {
        movieInfo = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return movieInfo;
}

public void loadMovies() {
    // Get the Preference settings Popular is default setting
    String sortPref = Utility.getPreferredSortSetting(application);
    repository.getMovies(sortPref)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(() -> movieInfo.setValue(repository.getMoviesLiveData().getValue()))
            .subscribe();
}
```

I'm observing my `ViewModel` in the `Fragment` like so -

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MovieFragmentViewModel.class);
viewModel.loadMovies();
viewModel.getMovieInfo().observe(this, movieInfos -> {
    this.movies.clear();
    if (movieInfos != null) {
        this.movies.addAll(movieInfos);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

According to the docs, the viewmodel observe method should be called when the LiveData changes. But I'm not seeing any images being loaded in the GridView. 
The `doOnComplete` method in my ViewModel is setting an empty list of movies but it should call this Action after the Completable is complete, so I should have a list of movies from the DB. I can see that movies are being saved in the DB, but not getting them in my ViewModel.
This is my github branch - 
https://github.com/anklinuxboy/PopularMovies2/tree/ankit/room

Comment: Can we see your test code?

Comment: Don't have any tests for this. That's why I included the repo which contains the complete code.

Comment: First, remove the `doOnComplete()` and move its functionality into `subscribe()` and add an error handler. Second, write some tests, with logging to show when things get called. Your tests will help you understand the code.